# C - Address of variables in the activation records

Tags: c, memory, variables, activerecord, activation-record

What's the quickest, easiest way to find the memory address of the first local variable in the activation record? (In C..)

Doesn't matter what we have declared already. Could be simple as char *s = 'Hello world!'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that - the C standard doesn't even require that there *is* a stack, let alone requiring a standard way to find out the order in which variables were put on it.

Comment: Well.. it does require an area for "automatic storage" which is going to be implemented as a stack on pretty much every architecture. But of course the specific semantics of accessing that will differ from machine to machine :) +1

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to do this in C.  Any attempt to do this would be platform- and calling convention-specific.